# My breadboard is not working/doesn't have current

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, breadboard

I recently got a Raspberry Pi and a Raspberry Pi kit with a breadboard and a couple of LEDs. At first, the LEDs and the breadboard worked but now the LED is not working. I tried using different wires or LEDs or transistors or breadboard rows or other spots in the negative rail, I've tried everything. I think my breadboard can't connect current or something. How do I fix this?

Comment: Impossible to say as there is not enough information. Try taking a photo you made and drawing the circuit you intended to make and maybe they match or not, or LED is mounted with wrong polarity, or then maybe a software issue.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Post your wiring diagram, please. Does it have a resistor between the Pi and the LED?

Comment: Had you used a resistor in series with the LED when you lit it up ? If not, there's a chance that the LED or the driver in the Pi chip may be kaput due to the high current flow. Just noticed that jay already mentioned this.

Comment: You mentioned instructions from realpython.com/python-raspberry-pi/#led which shows a fritzing-type picture of a solderless breadboard; it might not be obvious from that tutorial that the holes are internally connected (row 6 ABCDE are one node, row 7 ABCDE are another node). What bothers me about that picture it that it looks like a 330 ohm resistor is meant to be in series with the LED; but if both ends of the resistor are connected to row 6, then the resistor isn't really part of the circuit, and nothing limits the LED current. Would be very bright until it fails. Photo to confirm?

Answer (score 3):

Troubleshooting is mostly a matter of ruling things out. Test the LED by connecting it to a known-working power supply and a current-limiting resistor. Something like a 5V supply with a 1k resistor should be sufficient. If the LED works, then you know it isn't at fault and can turn your attention to the breadboard.

To test the breadboard, use your multimeter set to continuity. Insert jumper wires into each end of a bus connection and check for continuity. If the multimeter beeps (or shows roughly 0 ohms) then you know the breadboard is not at fault.

When you say "can't connect current" that does not make sense. Perhaps you meant that it "can't conduct current," implying that it has an open. Breadboards are mostly made up of small metal "U" shaped channels fitted into a plastic enclosure. It could be that the channels are not making good contact with component pins. They are meant to be bent in such a way that inserted leads have a reasonable friction fit and electrical continuity. However, some breadboards can have very loose-fitting channels; try a different breadboard to also rule your existing one in or out of the fault diagnosis.